# Foreach not displaying multiple contents

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I have a little problem in my Shortcode which I am creating for WordPress. The foreach loop is not displaying multiple posts each time. I'm not sure why is it doing this because if I `var_dump` the `$post` variable it shows that both the posts are available to that variable, can someone help me out please?

CODE:

```
function notes_shortcode($atts) {
global $post;

$atts = shortcode_atts( array( 'category' => $args["category"]), $atts, 'notes' );
$args = array( 'category_name' => $atts["category"]);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
$date = get_the_date( 'd', $post->ID );
$month = get_the_date( 'M', $post->ID );

    foreach( $posts as $post ) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        $imgURL = getpostImage( $post->ID );
        $title = get_the_title( $post->ID );
        $content = substr(get_the_content() , 0, 125); 
        $post = '<div class="animated fadeInUp" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="200" style="opacity: 0;">';
        $post .= '<div class="col-md-4 bloglist">';
        $post .= '<div class="post-content">';
        $post .= '<div class="post-image">';
        $post .= '<div class="flexslider blog-slider">';
        $post .= '<div class="overlay" style="opacity: 0;"></div>';
        $post .= '<div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">';
        $post .= '<ul class="slides" style="width: 800%; -webkit-transition: 0s; transition: 0s; -webkit-transform: translate3d(-350px, 0px, 0px);">';
        $post .= '<li class="clone" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 350px; float: left; display: block;"> <img src="' . $imgURL  . '" alt="" draggable="false"> </li>';
        $post .= '<li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 350px; float: left; display: block;"> <img src="' . $imgURL  . '" alt="" draggable="false"> </li>';
        $post .= '<li style="width: 350px; float: left; display: block;"> <img src="' . $imgURL  . '" alt="" draggable="false"> </li>';
        $post .= '<li class="clone" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 350px; float: left; display: block;"> <img src="' . $imgURL  . '" alt="" draggable="false"></li>';
        $post .= '</ul></div></div></div>';
        $post .= '<div class="date-box"><span class="day">' . $date . '</span>';
        $post .= '<span class="month">' . $month . '</span> </div>';
        $post .= '<div class="post-text">';
        $post .= '<h3><a href="css/#">' . $title . '</a></h3>';
        $post .= '<p> ' . $content . '<br>';
        $post .= ' <a href="#" class="btn-text">Read More</a></p></div></div></div></div>';
        return $post;
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'notes', 'notes_shortcode' );

function getpostImage($postid) {
    if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)){
            $imgArray = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID), 'thumbnail' );
            $imgURL = $imgArray[0];
            return $imgURL;
    }
}
```

Thanks ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I solved the problem. I used the WordPress Filters to hook the `$buff` variable and returned it outside the loop, below is the solution if anyone needs it.

```
function notes_shortcode($atts) {
global $post;
global $buf;

$atts = shortcode_atts( array( 'category' => $args["category"], 'posts_per_page' => $args["posts_per_page"]), $atts, 'notes' );
$args = array( 'category_name' => $atts["category"], 'posts_per_page' => $atts["posts_per_page"] );
$posts = get_posts( $args );
$date = get_the_date( 'd', $post->ID );
$month = get_the_date( 'M', $post->ID );
$buf = '';
$postHolder = array(); 

foreach( $posts as $post ) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        $imgURL = getpostImage( $post->ID );
        $title = get_the_title( $post->ID );
        $content = substr(get_the_content() , 0, 125); 

        $buf .= '<div class="animated fadeInUp" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="200" style="opacity: 0;">';
        $buf .= '<div class="col-md-4 bloglist">';
        $buf .= '<div class="post-content">';
        $buf .= '<div class="post-image">';
        $buf .= '<div class="flexslider blog-slider">';
        $buf .= '<div class="overlay" style="opacity: 0;"></div>';
        $buf .= '<div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; max-width: 350px; max-height: 175px; padding-bottom: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px;">';
        $buf .= '<ul class="slides" style="width: 800%; -webkit-transition: 0s; transition: 0s; -webkit-transform: translate3d(-350px, 0px, 0px);">';
        $buf .= '<li class="clone" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 350px; float: left; display: block;"> <img src="' . $imgURL  . '" alt="" draggable="false"> </li>';
        $buf .= '<li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 350px; float: left; display: block;"> <img src="' . $imgURL  . '" alt="" draggable="false"> </li>';
        $buf .= '<li style="width: 350px; float: left; display: block;"> <img src="' . $imgURL  . '" alt="" draggable="false"> </li>';
        $buf .= '<li class="clone" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 350px; float: left; display: block;"> <img src="' . $imgURL  . '" alt="" draggable="false"></li>';
        $buf .= '</ul></div></div></div>';
        $buf .= '<div class="date-box"><span class="day">' . $date . '</span>';
        $buf .= '<span class="month">' . $month . '</span> </div>';
        $buf .= '<div class="post-text">';
        $buf .= '<h3><a href="css/#">' . $title . '</a></h3>';
        $buf .= '<p> ' . $content . '<br>';
        $buf .= ' <a href="#" class="btn-text">Read More</a></p></div></div></div>';
        $buf .= apply_filters( 'post_class', '</div>', $atts );
    } 
    $buf .= apply_filters( 'post_class', '', $atts );
    return $buf;
}

add_shortcode( 'notes', 'notes_shortcode' );

function getpostImage($postid) {
    if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)){
            $imgArray = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID), 'thumbnail' );
            $imgURL = $imgArray[0];
            return $imgURL;
    }
}
```

Thankyou all for the help ..

Comment: Just a side note: why do use use global on top the function ? you're not using (at least I hope) a glablly declared var, so thoose lines are of no use here. [See this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) for a detail on the use of global for changing scope. (you're function getpostid in other hand use `$post->id` instead of the function argument, is this intentionnal (I suspect it works because of global, but sounds like an error) ) ?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the function, that means that your are making the function end. What you can do is send the array and then loop it later.Use the code below

```
function notes_shortcode($atts) {
global $post;

$atts = shortcode_atts( array( 'category' => $args["category"]), $atts, 'notes' );
$args = array( 'category_name' => $atts["category"]);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
$date = get_the_date( 'd', $post->ID );
$month = get_the_date( 'M', $post->ID );
$array = array();
    foreach( $posts as $post ) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        $imgURL = getpostImage( $post->ID );
        $title = get_the_title( $post->ID );
        $content = substr(get_the_content() , 0, 125); 
        $post = '<div class="animated fadeInUp" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="200" style="opacity: 0;">';
        $post .= '<div class="col-md-4 bloglist">';
        $post .= '<div class="post-content">';
        $post .= '<div class="post-image">';
        $post .= '<div class="flexslider blog-slider">';
        $post .= '<div class="overlay" style="opacity: 0;"></div>';
        $post .= '<div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">';
        $post .= '<ul class="slides" style="width: 800%; -webkit-transition: 0s; transition: 0s; -webkit-transform: translate3d(-350px, 0px, 0px);">';
        $post .= '<li class="clone" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 350px; float: left; display: block;"> <img src="' . $imgURL  . '" alt="" draggable="false"> </li>';
        $post .= '<li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 350px; float: left; display: block;"> <img src="' . $imgURL  . '" alt="" draggable="false"> </li>';
        $post .= '<li style="width: 350px; float: left; display: block;"> <img src="' . $imgURL  . '" alt="" draggable="false"> </li>';
        $post .= '<li class="clone" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 350px; float: left; display: block;"> <img src="' . $imgURL  . '" alt="" draggable="false"></li>';
        $post .= '</ul></div></div></div>';
        $post .= '<div class="date-box"><span class="day">' . $date . '</span>';
        $post .= '<span class="month">' . $month . '</span> </div>';
        $post .= '<div class="post-text">';
        $post .= '<h3><a href="css/#">' . $title . '</a></h3>';
        $post .= '<p> ' . $content . '<br>';
        $post .= ' <a href="#" class="btn-text">Read More</a></p></div></div></div></div>';
        $array[] = $post;
    }
return $array;
}
add_shortcode( 'notes', 'notes_shortcode' );

function getpostImage($postid) {
    if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)){
            $imgArray = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID), 'thumbnail' );
            $imgURL = $imgArray[0];
            return $imgURL;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I think this should work but somehow, its not. I dont know why, it outputs me on "Array" I think there is simple mistake in code.

Comment: ..and beside that, you're trying to modify the data WITHIN the foreach. This is not possible without using either 1. another auxiliary variable, or 2. updating $post variable by reference. Please note : "In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference. " See here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Downvoting, because of array return and the use of the iterator as new variable inside the loop (change it, and add an array_join at least, but it's of no use here, better see the self answer of @FahadSohail ).